# ajax clean up if possible on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, code-cleanup

i have this piece of code that finally works for me

```
  $(function(){
      $('.submit1').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "delanno.php",
              data: $("#myform1").serialize(),
              beforeSend: function(){
                  $('#result').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
              },
              success: function(data){
                  $('#result').html(data);
              }
          });
      });
      $('.deleter').on('click', function(){
          $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();
      }) 
  }); 

    $(function(){
      $('.submit2').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "delanno.php",
              data: $("#myform2").serialize(),
              beforeSend: function(){
                  $('#result').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
              },
              success: function(data){
                  $('#result').html(data);
              }
          });
      });
      $('.deleter').on('click', function(){
          $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();
      }) 
  }); 
      $(function(){
      $('.submit3').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "delanno.php",
              data: $("#myform3").serialize(),
              beforeSend: function(){
                  $('#result').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
              },
              success: function(data){
                  $('#result').html(data);
              }
          });
      });
      $('.deleter').on('click', function(){
          $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();
      }) 
  });
```

is it possible to combine all 3 sets into 1 piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the buttons don't have any other classes, and if so you can get the last digit with `this.className.slice(-1)` and target all buttons with one event handler and use the last digit to get the right form :

```
$(function(){
    $('[class^="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        var n = this.className.slice(-1);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'delanno.php',
            data : $('#myform' + n).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });

        $('.deleter').on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();
        }); 
    });
});
```

as suggested in the comments, if the submit buttons are inside the relevant forms, you should use an actual submit button and catch the submit event, not the click event on the button :

```
$(function(){
    $('[id^="myform"]').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'delanno.php',
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });

        $('.deleter').on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Or if each submit button is inside its corresponding form `data:$(this).closest("form").serialize()`...

Comment: @nnnnnn if they are submit buttons inside the form - it would probably be best to use the form.submit function though

Comment: I don't think the `$('.deleter').on('click'...` is inside the submit onclick.

Comment: I'd rather do `$(this.form).serialize()` then use `closest()`, but I edited the answer, and indeed, listening for the submit event would be more appropriate if the submit buttons are inside the forms.

Comment: first piece of code worked flawlessly, my submit button is inside the form, 2nd piece of code didnt work

Comment: @ioums, its not, its a div, the submit button is nested in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be...

```
post = function (ele) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "delanno.php",
         data: $(ele).serialize(),
         beforeSend: function () {
             $('#result').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
         },
         success: function (data) {
             $('#result').html(data);
         }
     });
 };

 $(function () {
     $('.submit1').on('click', post($('#submit1')));
     $('.submit2').on('click', post($('#submit2')));
     $('.submit3').on('click', post($('#submit3')));
     $('.deleter').on('click', function () {
         $(this).closest('.announce-box').remove();
     });
 });
```

Comment: this gives me a syntax error, not sure why, near the first .submit1